# How to for each a dataset for each button?

Tags: c#, sql, loops, iterator, dataset

What is the syntax for iterating through a column and changing the values to each button as it iterates?

Example : I have an SQL table with a column named OK with values (0 or 1) and 20 buttons on a form, each button corresponds to a row (button 1 to row 1, button 2 to row 2...etc). I want to iterate through all 20 rows in my dataset and for each row to assign 0 or 1 to its corresponding button (as in button text)

EDIT : I didnt try anything yet cause i dont know exactly how, i know you can iterate through the rows with

```
Foreach (DataRow drow in table.Rows)
{
    foreach(Button X in this.Controls
    {
    // It was my idea but it clearly doesnt work
    }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried to do? Do you expect us to do the entire method for you?

Comment: Please provide at least a base implementation that you have tried

Comment: Create the buttons within your outer foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

//Sample for MySqlDB

```
using MySql;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

private List<string> NumberfromDb = new List<string>();
private int SingleValue = -1;    

string QueryGetListUsers = "Select <tablename>.<Columname> From <tablename>;";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, m_mySqlConnection);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
 SingleValue = rdr.GetInt32("OK").ToString();
 NumberfromDb.Items.Add(SingleValue);
}
```

Now you have the Value in the List Just pass it in the "For" loop and assign it to the Button

eg:
     `btn1.Text = NumberfromDb[i].ToString();`